# Setting up iptables or ssh port forwarding for connecting to mysql

Tags: port-forwarding

I've got a linux (ubuntu) computer at work from where I can connect to an external mysql server (not on company NAT). I've also got a laptop from which I want to connect to the mysql server but outside the work network.

How can I setup iptables or ssh port forwarding on my workstation so that it forwards connections to it (from my laptop at home) to the external mysql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can ssh into your work computer do this on your home computer:

```
ssh -L 3306:mysqlserver:3306 user@workcomputer
```

and to connect to mysql, run this on your home computer:

```
mysql -h localhost
```

This forwards your local port 3306 off to the mysql server that your work computer can connect to.

Comment: I removed the comment where I said that this was not what I wanted because it was exactly what I wanted I just didn't understand it. Works great, thanks!